# How to separate binary code from source in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have my source next to a build directory

```
ocamlc -c file1.ml
ocamlc -c file2.ml
…
ocamlc -o main.ml ….cmo
```

I have the source with the file generated by the compilation.

I would like an option of `ocamlc` that enable me to have this file in the build directory.

I know i can do `ocamlc -o build/main.ml .....cmo` but i would like to have to .cmo in the build directory too

Thank you for your help

Comment: FYI the standard way for formatting code in StackOverflow consists in using a 4-space indentation, rather than backticks at each line (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Also, beware that your command `ocamlc -o main.ml ….cmo` won't have the action intended, because the option `-o` takes an argument (main.ml in your example), which is the path of the binary that will be **overwritten** by the compilation. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259147) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of your main question is very simple:
in order to put the main binary of your OCaml application in the `build` folder, you just need to run:

```
ocamlc -o build/main.exe main.ml ….cmo
```

Indeed as indicated in the documentation (`man ocamlc`):

> `-o exec-file`
>     Specify the name of the output file produced by the linker.  The
>     default  output  name  is a.out, in keeping with the Unix tradition. […]

However, doing all the build steps by hand in the way you are suggesting in your question may not be very effective (in particular, all *.cmo* files will stay along with the sources in the same folder).

To avoid this and facilitate the build of your OCaml project, I suggest using a build management tool for OCaml, for example one of the four tools mentioned in the end of the tutorial [Compiling OCaml Projects](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/compiling_ocaml_projects.html#Automated-build-systems):

- ocamlbuild
- GNU make
- OMake
- Oasis

([ocamlbuild](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ocamlbuild/) is probably the easiest tool to use among the four.)

But you may also consider using [Dune (formerly known as JBuilder)](https://github.com/ocaml/dune), which is the build system used by a majority of packages in [opam](https://opam.ocaml.org/).

Comment: Just a comment.  OMake put the object and executable files in the same directory as the source files by default.  You can change it by tweaking OMakefile, but it is VERY hard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to have the .cmo in the build too.

Comment: @Pierre-olivierGendraud yes: either you just do this by hand (by replacing `ocamlc -c file1.ml` with e.g. `(cd build && ocamlc -c ../file1.ml)`) or as advised in my answer, you use an OCaml build management tool such as ocamlbuild that takes care of that feature automatically for you.

Comment: BTW a good place to start with ocamlbuild can be to look at the first [examples given in its GitHub repo](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#examples)